# How to disable curve25519 in asp?

Tags: asp.net, ssl, curve

Is there any way to disable curve25519/x25519 in asp.net ? I know this command Disable-TlsEccCurve -Name curve25519 in powershell works but I want to do that in code. any help ?

Answer (score 0):

It does not need to change anything in code . Setting Exchange Key to ECDH option in IISCrypto can control and check curves.